# MVC 3 Application making users login every 2 minutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a mvc 3 application that uses standard authorization and stock logon. After a user logs in it will take less than 2 minutes and they have to log back in.. Is there any fix for this??

Comment: Is your application pool recycling every couple of minutes?

Comment: It is happening only from one location or multiple locations/computers?

Comment: I do not know.. I am hosting it on a winhost server.. and it happens no matter what computer I visit the site from..

Comment: Have you tried setting a machineKey in your web.config? You can generate one at http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I had this problem was on an instance of nopCommerce running on a shared host. Frequent app pool recycles were causing my cookies to be treated as invalid and forcing my users to log in again.

The solution that worked for me was to manually set a `<machineKey>` in my `web.config` file. The default setting allows the framework to generate a key pair for you every time the app starts up, which explains why the forms auth cookies couldn't be decrypted anymore at the server and were treated as invalid.

You can generate a valid key pair at http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

Comment: I think more of the issue here is if your app is restarting that often (the OP has every two minutes?) is to figure out why your app pool is going down that often. That surely isn't any default setting, and will kill and sessions in applications, so something is kooky here in the OPs case. Two minutes is far too small.

Comment: @AdamTuliper, I agree that such frequent app pool resets are going to absolutely kill your app, especially if you're using things like nHibernate which needs a lot of initialization time on the first load.

Comment: not just kill your app - if this is happening, something is wrong and should be figured out rather than worked around with a machinekey. no hoster should be restarting your app pool every two minutes, so  I'm just saying something else is going on here : )

Answer (score 1):

In your root web.config, have you double checked the timeout property is set correctly?

```
<system.web>
...
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
...
<system.web>
```

Have you checked it is actually logging the person on (eg soon as you log in, can you browse to a second/third page and it still has them logged in)

Comment: They are staying logged in... I can go to several pages and then it just pops the login... Using this same setting in my web.config..

Comment: Is this happening when in debug using Visual Studio or when put on a server?

Comment: Its fixed now.. It was the server recycling app pools.. The work around was to use sql session states.. And to use a machine key..

Comment: Glad to hear you got it all sorted :)

Comment: Thanks for the time anyways.. I got another issue now with dropdownlistfor and setting the default value to the previous set value.. See my post of you think you might know how to achieve this..